# Reset form inputs after submit

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

So I got a form that looks like this:

```
<Form noValidate id="messageForm" onSubmit={(event) => {this.handleSendMessage(event)}}>
    <Form.Group as={Col} md="12" controlId="validationFormik01">
        <Form.Label bsPrefix="contact-title">{t('details.name')}</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
            type="input"
            placeholder={t('details.namePlaceholder')}
            value={values.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            name="name"
            isInvalid={!!errors.name}
        />
        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
            {errors.name}
        </Form.Control.Feedback>
    </Form.Group>
                        ...
```

This is just a fragment but the thing is I want for example to reset that first Form Group WITHOUT reseting the other ones. How can I achieve this?
I'm trying to reset the values after they get submitted inside this function:

```
handleSendMessage(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const { t } = this.props;
    const self = this;
    UserService.sendMessage(event, this.props).then(function (status){
        toast.notify(t('details.messageSent'));
        // I WANT TO RESET THE VALUES HERE
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I ended up solving it like this:

```
handleSendMessage(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const { t } = this.props;
    UserService.sendMessage(event, this.props).then(function (status){
        toast.notify(t('details.messageSent'));
    })
    event.target[0].value = '';
    event.target[1].value = '';
    event.target[2].value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your submit function just make particular value to blank like this -`this.setState({values:''});`

```
handleSendMessage(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const { t } = this.props;
    const self = this;
    UserService.sendMessage(event, this.props).then(function (status){
        toast.notify(t('details.messageSent'));
        // I WANT TO RESET THE VALUES HERE
    })
   this.setState({values:''});
}
```

Comment: This isn't working. Nothing happens when I do this.